# how to pretty-format an output string of a python object

Tags: python

If I got a `list` object with element of type `dict` nested and use `print` command to print the list out. The output may like this, **all pressed together in one line**.

```
[{'rule_range': u'ALL', 'rule_desc': u'\u6d4b\u8bd5\u89c4\u5219\u5b9e\u4f8b01', 'creator': u'65624', 'rule_tmpl_id': u'RT0001', 'order_id': u'1', 'id': 2L, 'def_ext_cols': None, 'rule_cycle': u'1', 'create_time': None, 'rule_expr': u'select * from records where year = 2000', 'def_cols': None, 'rule_status': u'1', 'rule_id': u'TEST0001', 'store': None, 'rule_name': u'TRuleInstance01'}, {'rule_range': u'ALL', 'rule_desc': u'\u6d4b\u8bd5\u89c4\u5219\u5b9e\u4f8b01', 'creator': u'65624', 'rule_tmpl_id': u'RT0001', 'order_id': u'2', 'id': 2L, 'def_ext_cols': None, 'rule_cycle': u'1', 'create_time': None, 'rule_expr': u'select * from records where temperature = 21', 'def_cols': None, 'rule_status': u'1', 'rule_id': u'TEST0001', 'store': None, 'rule_name': u'TRuleInstance01'}]
```

What I want is some formatted **output string**, is there some kind of formatter(just like json online formatter), or it can be realized in python code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pretty Print](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(the_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Pretty Print as suggested by @justhalf. But I had a hard time making this work, until I realised that my dict was too short (less than 80 characters which is the default width of `pprint`). I changed the width to 20 and now it prints correctly:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint([{"test":"value", "test2":"value"},{"test":[{"key":"value"}]}])
```

prints:

```
[{   'test': 'value', 'test2': 'value'}, {   'test': [{   'key': 'value'}]}]
```

but:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint([{"test":"value", "test2":"value"},{"test":[{"key":"value"}]}], width=20)
```

prints:

```
[{'test': 'value',
  'test2': 'value'},
 {'test': [{'key': 'value'}]}]
```